show-trace command isn't working in playwright
The show-trace command isn't working when I try to get the trace viewer to run locally.
I get this error in my console
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for NewFP:PlaywrightCode:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 4.5.13 @ line 129, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.google.code.gson:gson:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 2.8.6 @ line 134, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.apache.poi:poi:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 5.2.2 @ line 141, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 5.2.2 @ line 146, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.opencsv:opencsv:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 5.5.2 @ line 152, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 1.1.1 @ line 158, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 2.9.0 @ line 165, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar -> version 8.0.33 vs 8.0.28 @ line 184, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.opencsv:opencsv:jar -> version 5.5.2 vs 5.7.1 @ line 208, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< NewFP:PlaywrightCode >------------------------
[INFO] Building PlaywrightCode 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec:3.1.1:java (default-cli) @ PlaywrightCode ---
error: unknown command 'show-trace trace.zip'

Process finished with exit code 1

I need the trace viewer to run locally and show me the trace
